# How can I "translate" a node.js request to Python?

Tags: python, node.js

basically I've got the following code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
const request = require("request");
var body = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('body.json', 'utf8'));

var options = {                 
    method: 'POST',             
    uri: 'https://api.pagar.me/core/v5/orders',                    
    headers: {               
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Buffer.from("sk_test_*:").toString('base64'),
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'              
    },
    json : body
};    

request(options, function(error, response, body) {  
    console.log(response.body);
});
```

I've tried to do the following in Python:

```
import requests

headers = {'Authorization': 'token',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
            }

k = requests.post("https://api.pagar.me/core/v5/orders", headers=headers)
```

The node code works, but the python only returns 401, so I know the token is right as the node example works, what do I need to do here I'm a newbie.

Comment: You're not setting the same Authorization value.  401 is an authorization error.  Requests has a parameter to do Basic authorization: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/

Comment: I've tried using the string "Basic " + "token" in Python, but didn't work still, I'm not sure about node, but does the from("sk_test_*:") loads anything other than the token?

Comment: It doesn't do anything with a token.  It creates a simple string with username "sk_test_*" and no password, and base64-encodes it, which is what Basic auth uses.  Just add `auth=("sk_test_","")` to the `requests.post` call.

Comment: Those two requests don't look the same to me. In the Python request you don't have the same authorization, nor do you have a request body. I'm trying to decide what you mean by "translate."